# How to create web animations with video — like apple.com/ipad-air

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

I am working on a project that I would like to have a video animate, kind of like what Apple does on their iPad Air page.

Take a visit to apple.com/ipad-air and you will see what I mean. The iPad moves through each "slide" on the web page.

My question is this: how do you get those animations to work? I was looking through their code and saw the iPad was just a big .mp4 file. It seems like it stops at certain keyframes. Are there any jquery libraries that could help me do this?

Also, I want to be able to support older browsers. How would I detect browsers and be able to support older ones, too?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Use [onepage-scroll](https://github.com/peachananr/onepage-scroll) and set CSS3 effects via [callback functions](https://github.com/peachananr/onepage-scroll#callbacks).

Additional info:

[Demo](http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/onepage_scroll_demo.html)
[OnePageScroll.js: Creating an Apple’s iPhone 5S Website](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2013/09/18/onepagescroll-js-creating-an-apples-iphone-5s-website/)

Comment: He says he want to support old browsers. I would then recommend [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) as onePageScroll doesn't. Here's a demo where you can see the use of callbacks and animations: http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/apple.html

Comment: Also, it works better for mobile devices and add quite a few more options.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I could be wrong here, but it does look like the animation is **initially** an mp4, but the rest are done through CSS3 animations on the images of each step. If you look inside their code, using like Chrome Dev tools, you'll see that they have  tags for each "subpage" (like Design, Performance, Wireless, etc). For example, take a look at this HTML they have:

```
<section class="scene active" id="design" data-track-visitor-engagement="design">
            <div class="scene-content">
                <img class="hero-img centered" src="http://images.apple.com/ipad-air/overview/images/desktop/design_hero_2x.jpg" width="498" height="640" alt="">
                <div class="container centered fade-slide">
                    <h1><img src="http://images.apple.com/ipad-air/overview/images/desktop/design_title_2x.png" width="325" height="220" alt="All-new design. A ton of advanced technology. In just one pound."></h1>
                    <p class="intro">You have to hold iPad&nbsp;Air to believe it. It’s just 7.5 millimeters thin and weighs just one pound. The stunning Retina display sits inside thinner bezels, so all you see is your content. And an incredible amount of power lies inside the sleek enclosure. So you can do so much more. With so much&nbsp;less.</p>
                    <p class="intro"><a class="more" href="/ipad-air/design/" onclick="s_objectID=&quot;http://www.apple.com/ipad-air/design/_2&quot;;return this.s_oc?this.s_oc(e):true">Learn more about design</a></p>
                </div>
                <ul class="tiles centered fade-slide">
                    <li><img src="http://images.apple.com/ipad-air/overview/images/desktop/design_details_weight_2x.png" width="100" height="100" alt="1 pound"></li>
                    <li><img src="http://images.apple.com/ipad-air/overview/images/desktop/design_details_lighter_2x.png" width="100" height="100" alt="28% lighter"></li>
                    <li><img src="http://images.apple.com/ipad-air/overview/images/desktop/design_details_thinner_2x.png" width="100" height="100" alt="20% thinner"></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Then, you'll see that in .fade-slide, they have `-webkit-transition:` in their CSS. This is what is animating those images after the mp4 file does. [Take a look at CSS transitions here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions)

Also, I'm sure they have some sort of javascript/jQuery failsafe for older browsers (or a more simple version of this for older browsers, though Apple is known to be bleeding edge, so if they didn't have it, that wouldn't surprise me).

Anyway, that's just a high level explanation of how they do it :).

Answer (score 0):

According to a variety of articles available around the web, in order to achieve the effects you mention, Apple uses a combination of the HTML5 canvas, loose images and javascript.

They also use a very specific technique to animate a row of JPG images.

> Instead of using video, some brilliant minion at Apple came up with the idea of compressing animation into a handful of JPEG images by showing the starting and ending frames, then using special JPEGs like the one at the top of this post that contain only the updated and animated portions of the image. A JSON file is used to specify how the updated bits are positioned, and the actual logic for displaying the "video" in a  element is found in a tiny Javascript.

([Source](http://www.tuaw.com/2012/10/16/how-apples-iphone-5-website-works/))

**Tools**

There are applications out there that try to mimic similar results, but from what i have seen, none can deliver anything at the quality of what is shown on the Apple website. Just in case, here are two options:

- [Sequence JS](http://www.sequencejs.com)
- [Phosphor](http://www.divergentmedia.com/phosphor)

**General thoughts**

Bear in mind that Apple is a top-notch business with brutally huge sales figures. They have the budget to arrange for a team of high-end super qualified programmers and designers in order to maintain their innovative status, even on the web.

If you'd like to achieve similar effects, you should start with small steps.

Answer (score 0):

For manipulation of `<video>` elements, I recommend [popcorn.js](http://popcornjs.org/). It should allow you two way bind to positions in the video. You can then use javascript or css3 animations to control the location of the `<video>` and other surrounding elements on the page.

For animating the surrounding elements with scroll in-mind, I recommend (shameless plug of my favorite lib) [greensock](http://www.greensock.com/). Greensock will let you set up the animation of all the elements in your presentation as a timeline that can then be paused, reversed, or seeked.

Combining

- [popcorn.js](http://popcornjs.org/)
- [greensock](http://www.greensock.com/)

is the best and most flexible way I know of to produce these kind of presentations.

---

here is an example of a scroll presentation lib built on greensock

http://johnpolacek.github.io/superscrollorama/

here is an example using 2 way video control via popcorn

http://client.heliozilla.com/aer/demo_06.html